# An algebra generated by antiderivatives of continuous function.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

> **Problem:** Let $A \subseteq C[0,1]$ be uniformly dense subspace, and $$B:= \{ F(x) : F(x) = \int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt , 0 \leq x \leq 1 , f \in A\}. $$
>   Then, $B$ is uniformly dense in $C_{0}[0,1] : = \{g \in C[0,1] : g(0)=0 \}.$

I know that if I show that $B$ is an algebra separates points, then Stone-Weierstrass theorem gives the desired result. However, I don't know how to show that $B$ is an algebra.

To show $B$ is an algebra, we need to show that $\forall F,G \in B$, $FG \in B$. Let $$F:= \int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt, \quad G:= \int_{0}^{x}g(s)ds $$
for some $f,g \in C_{0}[0,1]$. Then,
$$FG(x) = \int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt\int_{0}^{x}g(s)ds = \int_{0}^{x}\int_{0}^{x}f(t)g(s)dsdt. $$ 
Using Tonelli on $|f(t)|$ and $|g(t)|$, we can conclude that $|f(t)g(s)| \in L^{1}(m^2)$, so by the Fubini, we can conclude that 
$$FG(x) = \int_{0}^{x}\int_{0}^{x}f(t)g(s)dsdt = \int_{[0,x]^{2}}f(t)g(s)d(s\times t) =\int_{0}^{x}\int_{0}^{x}f(t)g(s)dtds. $$

However, I think these results are not much helpful for showing that $FG \in B$. Could you let me know a hint?

Comment: SW is overkill. Given a function $f$ that vanishes at 0, find a $C^1$ function $g$ close to $f$ and vanishing at zero and then find an element $h$ of $A$ close to $g'$. Then the antiderivative of $h$ will be an element of $B$ close to $f$.

Comment: @Ian Thank you very much, I will try your approach and update my answer soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show that you have an algebra, all you need to show is that $FG$ has a continuous derivative and $FG=0$ at $0$.
$$
               (FG)' = F'G+FG'
$$
$F',F,G',G$ are continuous and $F,G$ vanish at $0$. So $FG$ is in the algebra.